# Add object via UI

Tags: swift, storyboard

I am using [this library to add a TextField](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material/wiki/TextField) in Swift.  I can see how to programmatically add it in code, but I want to know how to add it via the Xcode UI.  I want to be able to position it in Storyboard.

I tried to edit this line

```
@IBOutlet weak var txtOlja: TextField!
```

but that had no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only add it in Storyboard if the control was `@IBDesignable`.

Since this particular control can't be rendered in Interface Builder, your only option is to programmatically constrain it using Auto Layout.